# preferredContentSize not working for an iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, popover

As I know popovers are meant for iPads but I'm trying to implement one in an iPhone app.

I need to show popover (with certain size) view controller `PopoverVC` in my main view controller `HomeVC`

Here is how I call popover in my `HomeVC`:

```
- (IBAction)optionsAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    CBOptionsPopoverViewController *optionsViewController = [[CBOptionsPopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CBOptionsPopoverNibIdentifier bundle:nil];
    optionsViewController.delegate = self;
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    optionsViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 100.0);
    self.optionsPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 100);
    [self presentViewController:optionsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And here is what I do in `PopoverVC` class:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        self.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle) adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
    return UIModalPresentationPopover; //You have to specify this particular value in order to make it work on iPhone.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 100.0);
}
```

The problem is that it covers my whole screen, but I need only certain size. 
May be there are some issues with the fact that I'm doing the app for iPhone? or `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` where i return UIModalPresentationPopover ?

**EDIT:**
I also added this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        self.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    }
    return self; 
}
```

But didn't help. 
According to the comment. I used debugger and all 4 functions from `PopoverVC` are being called.

Also when I debug and do "po self.preferredContentSize" it shows that size is 320x100. Even when it's full screen (after user sees the page not before). That means that it just doesn't listen to the `preferredContentSize`

Comment: Use the debugger! Your PopoverVC `init` is never being called, because you are not _calling_ PopoverVC's `init`. You are calling `[[CBOptionsPopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CBOptionsPopoverNibIdentifier bundle:nil]`.